# Query to match multiple column values with multiple rows

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table in my postgresql 9.1

Table `contact`:

```
contact_id     phone     mobile
1               123       456
2               111       222
3               333       123
4               222       444
```

Table `role`:

```
contact_fk        exchange
7                 1
8                 2
1                 4
5                 5
2                 4
4                 5
```

I need the result like:

```
contact_id      phone    mobile      exchange
1               123       456         4
3               333       123         4
2               111       222         4
```

I want all the contact data whose mobile field data is in any other contacts phone field and the user must be in exchange 4, which is available in `contact_role` table

FYI: the contact table contains around 50k rows so joining the contact table to itself taking a lot time, so we must apply the `contact_role` condition together.

Comment: So what did you try? Looks like a simple inner join should do it?

Comment: how i use inner join with another table (contact_role),  select a.mobile,b.phone,a.contact_id from contact a inner join contact b on b.mobile = a.phone;      It is taking a lot time and quits cant see the results

Answer (score 0):

Joining 50k table with 2 columns (where contact_fk is probably primary) shouldn't take long time.

```
SELECT t1.contact_id, t1.phone, t1.mobile, t2.exchange
FROM contact as t1
JOIN role as t2 ON t1.contact_id = t2.contact_fk
WHERE t2.exchange = 4
```

Or if you have index on exchange column, this probably will be faster:

```
SELECT t1.exchange, t2.contact_id, t2.phone, t2.mobile
FROM role as t1
JOIN contact as t2 ON t1.contact_fk = t2.contact_id
WHERE t1.exchange = 4
```

Comment: i need comparison between mobile and phone field of two rows in contact table

Comment: like t1.mobile = t1.phone

Comment: @user3699269 you don't mention that in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
select      t1.contact_id,
            t1.phone,
            t1.mobile,
            t2.phone,
            t2.exchange 

from        contact t1 

inner join (select      contact_id,
                        mobile,
                        phone,
                        exchange 

            from        contact, contact_role 

            where       contact.contact_id = contact_fk 
                and     exchange = 4
            ) t2 
    on      t1.mobile = t2.phone 
    and     t1.mobile != '';
```